# ActiveX control '827b9baa-d3cc-41ad-a0a8-5f383261b792' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have read all about threading models and the STAThread attribute however none of these solves my problems as I am creating web service with a dll as opposed to a winforms project so there is no Main function with which to utilize this attribute.

My web service calls the dll and The error is thrown in my dll.

```
AxFKAttendLib.AxFKAttend oAttendanceControl = new AxFKAttendLib.AxFKAttend();
```

Comment: It's *highly* likely then that the control was never meant to be used within a web service. You could *try* to create a separate thread and use [`Thread.SetApartmentState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx) on it before starting it, but I'd still be doubtful.

Comment: It looks like a ActiveXControl. Why do you need to create instance of a control in web service? Who is going to see that?

Comment: I need the functions of the dll that the ocx uses, there is no visual interface

Comment: @user985197 - there may be no visual interface, but it may still rely on there being a windows message pump running, as an example, to achieve its purposes. I'd strongly suggest you find another component/library that does whatever this ocx does but isn't tied into an ActiveX control.